# php purchase page, not passing values to addcart page. How do i pass these values?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to php and still struggling with my project. I am unable to pass the values of the product
selected to the addcart page. Can you see what I am missing, I feel like I am getting so close.

Product Page:

```
$display6="SELECT * 
    FROM in_product LIMIT $start, $pagerows; " ; 
$displayResult6 = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display6)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult6, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {  
$i = 1;
$x = $row6['ip_stock'];
$y = " ";
for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
$y .= "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";
 }            
echo "<tr>
<form action='addcartInstate.php' method='post' name='addtocartForm' id='addtocartForm' >
<input type='hidden' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' /></td>
<td class='td2'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add to Cart' /></td>
<td class='td2'><strong> " . $row6['ip_name'] . " </strong><br> " . $row6['ip_desc'] . " <br> $" . $row6['ip_price'] . " </td>
<td class='td2'><img alt='first' src=" . $row6['ip_image'] . " width='300' height='250'></td>
 <td class='td2'><br>
     <b>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br>
            <select id='orderIn_quantity' name='orderIn_quantity'>
                <option value='Select'> Select </option> 
                " . $y . "                                              
            </select>
 </td>
 </form>
</tr>";
```

}
    echo "";

Add To cart page:

```
if(isset($_GET['ip_id'])) {
        $ip_id = $_GET['ip_id'];
        } elseif (isset($_POST['ip_id'])) {
        $ip_id = $_POST['ip_id'];
        }

    if(isset($_POST['orderIn_quantity'])) {
        $orderIn_quantity = $_POST['orderIn_quantity'];
        }

$display="SELECT * 
    FROM in_product WHERE ip_id = '$ip_id'; " ; 
$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display)
            or die (mysqli_error($dbhandle));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult);          
$orderIn_total = $row['ip_price'] * $orderIn_quantity; 

$orderIn_complete = "No";

$insert = "INSERT INTO order_instate(user_id, ip_id, orderIn_quantity, orderIn_total, orderIn_complete )
                VALUES ('$user_id', '$ip_id', '$orderIn_quantity', '$orderIn_total', '$orderIn_complete' )"; 

        $addInsert=mysqli_query($dbhandle, $insert)
                        or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle)); 

        if ($addInsert != NULL) {
            echo "<h3>This product has been added to your shopping cart. </h3>";
        }
```

?>

Comment: The specific problem is....It does not get the values ip_id or

Comment: orderIn_quantity from the product page. How can I pass those values successfully?

Comment: `ip_id` isn't passed because you don't have a `name` attribute on the hidden form field. That said, you have quite a few other issues with your code, including security and logic problems. For instance, you should not use any user supplied values directly in SQL without proper escaping (or better using prepared statements). Also, shouldn't you check that you have the inventory available before adding it to the cart (keep in mind, someone can post whatever values they want to your form handler, and aren't restricted by the values in your form)?

Comment: I appreciate your help! adding the name attribute has certainly helped in passing that value. I am no longer getting any errors,

Comment: but the value of the quantity is still not passing. It gives me a zero value, which obviously changes the code. My select drop down menu is dynamically populated through the database, so you can ONLY select from the amount available in stock, which I will then adjust based on successful orders. Could you help me pass the orderIn_quantity value?

Comment: OH, just an fyi, the user has no way to input anything into this code, they can select an amount, and add it to the cart, there are no text fields for user input.

Comment: Someone can post anything they want to your `addcartInstate.php` handler, and aren't restricted by the values you setup in your form. In other words, someone could easily post a quantity of -500, and your code would happily accept it. Worse, because you're not escaping the posted values, it would be trivial for someone to use SQL injection attacks to download all the user information or simply destroy your entire database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still new, so I want to make sure I understand, although this does not solve my current problem of not being able to pass the quantity selected in the drop down menu. But since the user only has a drop down menu with the amount available in stock as the only selections available, how would they enter -500?

Comment: And in the process of my security education, which I am grateful, could we discuss how to solve my issue of not being able to pass the amount of the quantity selected?

Comment: is there something like a getSelectedIndex for a drop down menu to grab the selected value?

Comment: The very first fundamental rule of web programming is never, ever trust user supplied values. Anything that comes from `$_POST` or `$_GET` is supplied by the user (a user can change these values using nothing more than the built in developer tools in their browser) and could be anything, regardless of what values are available on your form. Consider what would happen if someone posted `ip_id` as something like `';TRUNCATE in_product;`. This would most likely result in your `in_product` table being deleted.

Comment: Regarding your quantity issue, the line `$y .= "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";` isn't doing what you want, and you're posting something like ' . 1 . ' as your quantity. Try `$y .= "<option value='" . $i . "'> $i </option>";` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what you are saying and will spend the day making my code more robust. This did correct my issue and I thank you for taking time to educate us beginners.